# Model a Doctor working shift table/collection?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, calendar, nosql

Imagine a doctor working at some hospital, he has a weekly working schedule and can update the schedule at a given date. So I have to implement a functionality where users can search and find docker's today's schedule.

I've created a schedules model with

- date - Date
- day- Weekday name
- startTime - time
- endTime - time
- status - active|inactive

the table can have a date or day, not both.

So when I have to find a duty schedule for a date for example -  19 July 2021 (Monday) then I do following

- find all schedules querying `date`
- then grab the ids of all schedules returned from the above query
- find all schedules with day (Monday, taken from date) and skip the above ids
  But I feel there must be a better way of doing this. This works well but wherever I want to do something about a doctor's duty schedule I have to run the above queries which do not feel good in terms of performance.

What are some ways I can achieve the same?